# Pin the Desktop shortcut to "Save as" dialog

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to create a pinned shortcut to Desktop (Área de trabalho - translated to portuguese).

The problem is, I don't want it to appear under Quick access (Acesso rápido).

I want it to be shown in a separated category, like the Dropbox and Onedrive categories highlighted below, otherwise I will have to click in the hierarchy arrow every time.

[image: "Save as" dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save this code to file and name it to `something.reg`, then run the file.
it takes effect immediately.
the icon is not exactly right though.  but I believe that's not a big deal.
in the code ,you can see the original source of it. I made some edits.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created by: Shawn Brink
; Created on: May 1st 2016
; Tutorial: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/48991-google-drive-navigation-pane-add-remove-windows-10-a.html


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}]
@="Desktop"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\shell32.dll,35"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4D,00,52,00,4F,00,4F,00,54,00,\
25,00,5C,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6D,00,33,00,32,00,5C,00,73,00,68,\
00,65,00,6C,00,6C,00,33,00,32,00,2E,00,64,00,6C,00,6C,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"=hex(2):25,00,75,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,\
  00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,25,00,5c,00,64,00,65,00,73,00,6b,00,74,00,6f,00,70,00,\
  00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\ShellFolder]
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}]
@="Desktop"
"System.IsPinnedToNamespaceTree"=dword:00000001
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000042

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\shell32.dll,35"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\InProcServer32]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,59,00,53,00,54,00,45,00,4D,00,52,00,4F,00,4F,00,54,00,\
25,00,5C,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6D,00,33,00,32,00,5C,00,73,00,68,\
00,65,00,6C,00,6C,00,33,00,32,00,2E,00,64,00,6C,00,6C,00,00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\Instance]
"CLSID"="{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\Instance\InitPropertyBag]
"Attributes"=dword:00000011
"TargetFolderPath"=hex(2):25,00,75,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,70,00,72,00,6f,00,66,\
  00,69,00,6c,00,65,00,25,00,5c,00,64,00,65,00,73,00,6b,00,74,00,6f,00,70,00,\
  00,00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}\ShellFolder]
"FolderValueFlags"=dword:00000028
"Attributes"=dword:f080004d

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}]
@="Desktop"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.